# Symfony2: ResourceNotFoundException when using extends in a twig template

Tags: php, symfony, routes, twig

I have over-ridden the exception.html.twig in the following directory:

```
app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception
```

I have another twig inside another bundle that I'd like to extend, so I did the following:

```
{% extends 'AcmeMainBundle::layout.html.twig' %}
```

but it always gives me this error:

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException' in /Users/Aditya/Sites/Acme/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php on line
```

Why is this?

Comment: You cleared the cache ?

Comment: Remember that you need to consider not using any context (such as `app` variable in Twig) when you overwrite exceptions, because some of them (such as a 404) are handled before that context is created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to generate a non-existant route in your template. Therefore the router throws the Exception.

Examine your template for route-generating calls like `path()` and make sure all used route-names actually exist. Clear your cache before to be sure you have the latest routes available.

you can debug your routing with the console command ...

```
app/console router:debug --env=prod
app/console router:debug --env=dev
```

.. to list all routes in your application. Further use ...

```
app/console router:debug route_name
```

for more detailed information.

**Tip:**

Sometimes you have routes only configured for the dev environment ( aka in routing_dev.yml ) and receive these errors in production.

Comment: I did the same line of code (extending this twig) on the main bundle and it worked just fine @nifr