# Symfony2 error page won't extend base.html.twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

My problem is the same as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111807/symfony2-custom-error-page-extend-base-html-twig) but my error page won't extend `base.html.twig`. `base.html.twig` doesn't seems to be the problem. When i try to extend base layout, I get `ResourceNotFoundException`. In other twig layouts specific to a ceratain bundle, it works but if I try to override error template, it throws this error.

The key problem is probably the ResourceNotFoundException but i know I'm extending it the right way...

```
extends '::base.html.twig'
```

I'm not new to Symfony2 and I've used template inheritance quite alot. If i try to run the error page without extending the base layout, the error page shows. I've done all the cache clearing, I've run it in the `prod` environment but the page won't extend the base layout.

Anyone knows what could be the problem? Is there any other way that i could get the resource to the error template or debug to see what path is Symfony looking for when searching `base.html.twig` but cannot find one?

Comment: Did you use "is_granted" in your layout? See there: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html#override-error-templates "You must not use is_granted in your error pages (or layout used by your error pages), because the router runs before the firewall."

Comment: I didn't use is_granted. I haven't implemented any security features.

Comment: Is it ok when you extends your base template from another templates? (Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510216/symfony2-resourcenotfoundexception-when-using-extends-in-a-twig-template )

Comment: I tried that an hour ago and it's still the same. I've also made a dummy test.html.twig in app/Resources/viwes directory and still throws that exception. I'm gonna have to implement an event listener on the exception to handle this.

Comment: :: means that it looks in the root views directory of the current bundle, so is base.html.twig in the same bundle as your error page  ?

Comment: @johnSmith `'::base.html.twig'` does not mean it is in `src/Vendor/NameBundle/Resources/views/` but in `app/Resources/views`.

Comment: This is not my first time that I do this. I've put base.html.twig inside app/Resources/views.